# Display first post on each page differently than the others

Tags: theme-development

I'm trying to work out how to show posts differently on each page. My wordpress blog will show 4 posts on one page. I want to show the first post to be bigger, with a larger feature post, a longer excerpt and a 'read more' button. The posts underneath are small excerpts with a post thumbnail on the left. I want this to display the same way when the pagination is clicked to show older posts - the first post always larger.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say how to implement it exactly without looking at your code. But the idea is to use the `$wp_query->current_post` variable that is always available in the main query. It would look something like this:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        global $wp_query;
        if ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 ) {
            // Output the first post
            continue;
        }
        // Output post
    }
}
```